# store the incoming messages in sorted order(as per the incoming numbers)

Tags: android, database, database-design

I am designing an app in that i am storing the incoming messages in my own created database and from this database i am displaying these messages in my application.
for this i am using this code,
To insert the data,

```
mydb =  openOrCreateDatabase("db",MODE_PRIVATE, null);                              
        mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sms_inbox (SMS_TEXT varchar , SENDER_NUMBER varchar );");      

        mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO sms_inbox VALUES('" + stBody + "', '" + stPhoneNumber + "');");
```

To read the data,

```
Cursor c = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * from sms_inbox", null);
```

and then i am displaying these messages,

So now my problem is this that I want to store these messages according to the phone numbers,
example,

phoneno.-12345
"ALL the messages of 12345 will be shown here"
phone no.-23456
"ALL the messages of 23456 will be shown here"

Comment: use order by in select query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could store those messages as another entry in `sms_inbox` table, but it would be helpful to store a timestamp as well to be able to distinguish each message.

When you query you could pass the phone number as what is the phone number you're interested into: `SELECT * from sms_inbox where 'SENDER_NUMBER' = '?'`

Or you could make a select ordered by SENDER_NUMBER: `SELECT * from sms_inbox order by 'SENDER_NUMBER' desc;`

In the end it all depends on the use-cases you have. You could also use another table for keeping only the messages for a number and map a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: but there is problem that while using SELECT * from sms_inbox where 'SENDER_NUMBER' = '?' as per your suggestion,i have to give the actual no. but i want to give a variable instead of this.              I know this is happening because the data saved into the data base will contain the actual no not the variable...but i want to resolve this problem..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean ... Couldn't you replace the variable in the query? like: "where 'sender_number' = \'" + myObj.getValue()  + "\';" ?

Comment: Got it,that was the same problem and now my problem has been resolved actually i dont know about sql queries means how to write them but thnx a lot GUNAR..

Comment: You're welcome ... please be very careful with SQL injection. You need to escape your queries. A quick google on this should guide you.